# how to use date_add using result from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Instead of using(this works):

```
db_query(UPDATE ost_ticket duedate=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) WHERE ticket_id=10);
```

I would like to replace '3' with output from the code below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT s.grace_period from ost_sla s, ost_ticket t where s.id=t.sla_id and t.ticket_id=10"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$ayam = $row["grace_period"];
```

However when i try this, it doesnt work:

```
db_query(UPDATE ost_ticket duedate=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$ayam.' DAY) WHERE ticket_id=10);
```

UPDATE: The original code is as below :

```
db_query('UPDATE '.TICKET_TABLE.' SET isanswered=0, duedate=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), lastmessage=NOW() WHERE ticket_id='.db_input($this->getId()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `db_query` a function in your php code? Then it should probably look like this:

```
db_query('UPDATE ost_ticket duedate=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$ayam.' DAY) WHERE ticket_id=10');
```